# Dynamic Vue Router variables without knowing the variable in advance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I followed the [Vue documentation on dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Which works fine **when you know in advance which :id** you wish to implement inside your router-link html tag.

[The live example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/4xfa2f19/)

```html
<router-link to="/user/foo">/user/foo</router-link>
```

However in my specific case, I do not know `foo` in advance.
I need to do some specific computation on the server **BEFORE** I know the `id` I want to render.

So, to sum up, what I need is the following :

- The user clicks on a button (button name : "Start Binding Batch")
- An `https request` is made on the server, which makes some calculation (Look for an object "Batch" to bind, based on specific conditions...) and then returns an `:id` of an object "Batch"
- The `vue-router` redirects the route to that id && displays the correct component (route : "bind_batch/:id", component: BindBatch)
- The user should be able to access any link with an id ("bind_batch/:id") and it would reload the proper component and vue
- Bonus: if there is no id to return, the server returns `null`, and the front-end would display a message stating that there is nothing to return ("Nothing to bind here")

**I found a way to make this work but it seems very "hacky".**
Could anyone point me to the correct direction or tell me if what I'm doing is wrong?

**application.js**

```js
    import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
    import ClerkApplication from '../clerk_application.vue'
    import BindBatch from '../components/bind_batch.vue'

    Vue.use(VueRouter)

    const router = new VueRouter({
      routes: [
        { path: '/bind_batch/:id', name: 'BindBatch', component: BindBatch }
      ]
    })

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      if (document.querySelector('#clerk-application')) {
        new Vue({
          el: "#clerk-application",
          components: { 'clerk-application': ClerkApplication },
          router: router
        })
      }
    })
```

**clerk_application.vue**

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <button class='btn btn-primary'
          v-on:click="startBinding()"
          v-if="!this.batchId && !this.showNoBatchToBind"
        >
          Start Binding Batch
        </button>

        <router-link
          :if="this.batchId"
          :to="'/bind_batch/' + this.batchId"
          class='hidden'
        >
        </router-link>

        <router-view></router-view>

        <div v-if="this.showNoBatchToBind">
          Nothing to bind here
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>


    <script>
      export default {
        props: ['clerk'],
        data: function () {
          return {
            showNoBatchToBind: false,
            batchId: parseInt(this.$router.currentRoute.fullPath.split('bind_batch/')[1]) || null
          }
        },
        methods: {
          startBinding: function () {
            return make_request("PUT", `/clerks/get_next_batch_to_bind`).then(
              (batchId) => {
                if(JSON.parse(batchId) != null) {
                  this.batchId = JSON.parse(batchId)
                  this.$router.push({ path: `bind_batch/${batchId}` })
                } else {
                  this.showNoBatchToBind = true
                }
              }
            )
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

**bind_batch.vue**

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        This is your batch {{ $route.params.id }}
      </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: have you looked into a navigation guard, so that you redirect to say `/user/` and it calls the server for the computation and then redirects once you get a response with the correct param

Comment: Hello, yes, i'm looking into it definitely :) If I figure it out with this technique i'll keep you posted !